# Xcode 11 Swift 5 - Unable to install app (failed to load info.plist file)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

As the title says, I am unable to install my app on a device or the simulator (builds successfully however).
The install only fails when I am using Cocoapods.

The reason for this seems to be that it cannot find the Info.plist file for the individual pods installed.

When I install to the simulator, I get the error message:

"This app could not be installed at this time:  Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path ...  Extra info about plist: ACL="

When I install to my device, I get the error message:

"Unable to install ."  The failure reason in the details is "Could not inspect the application package."

The pods failing (as an example) are ZIPFoundation and ReachabilitySwift.

Under the Pods project, if I select the framework under Targets, there is no Info.plist file available so I'm not sure if maybe the plist file is not getting copied over during the pods installation.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'app' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for app
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
  pod 'ZIPFoundation'

  target 'appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'appUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I am using Swift 5 in Xcode 11.2.1.

I've tried quite a few workarounds with no solution so any hints and information regarding the issue would be appreciated because I am unable to use any Pods in my project currently.

Edit:

I reproduced the issue with a fresh project.

In project folder, run pod init.
Add pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod install
open workspace
Build and run on simulator -> "This app could not be installed at this time"

Again, this was using Xcode 11.2.1.

Comment: sorry if this is a 'dumb' question, but, have you ran pod install and or pod update after you made this pod file?

Comment: there are no dumb questions.  and yes, I've also cleared the Pods folder, removed Podfile.lock and workspace then pod update.  and I've reset the simulator, deleted simulator cache, removed the DerivedData, and cleaned the build folder in Xcode @DawsonLoudon

Comment: @boppa did you solved it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue today. My cocoapods is stuck for any project after "pod install" has been run. It happened all of a sudden, just after installing: https://github.com/yiplee/YPNavigationBarTransition

Then I immediately uninstalled that plugin and cleared cache altogether. Also reinstalled cocoapods. No luck. I am trying to upgrade Xcode to 12 now hoping for some miracle to happen.

Edit: Workaround is to add a fake plist for all pods

general_pod_info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>FMWK</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>4.3.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}</string>
  <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
  <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image]

Comment: Great job!  this is a solution for temporary, apple must solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `use_frameworks!` from Podfile was the solution in my case. Following thread helped me to find out https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126598#398211